# "TypeError" when trying to render react-native-reanimated node in Jest test

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-reanimated

When trying to render my application in Jest to do some integration testing, I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'createNode' of undefined

      at AnimatedParam.createNode [as __nativeInitialize] (node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/core/AnimatedNode.js:126:24)
      at AnimatedParam.__nativeInitialize [as __attach] (node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/core/AnimatedNode.js:71:10)
      at new __attach (node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/core/AnimatedParam.js:11:10)
      at createAnimatedParam (node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/core/AnimatedParam.js:71:10)
      at createAnimatedFunction (node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/core/AnimatedFunction.js:38:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/derived/interpolate.js:17:39)
```

The code it is complaining about in `react-native-reanimated` looks like this:

```
  __nativeInitialize() {
    if (!this.__initialized) {
      ReanimatedModule.createNode(this.__nodeID, { ...this.__nodeConfig });
      this.__initialized = true;
    }
  }
```

And `ReanimatedModule` is a type alias for `NativeModule` from the `react-native` library. Beyond that, I have not found any useful information that helps solve this issue.

What is particularly strange here is that I am not directly using `react-native-reanimated` in my code base, and the only library components I can find that are using it are not being rendered in the components being tested, as far as I can tell.

I have not been able to slim down my code in any reasonable manner to reproduce this issue, and the code in question is protected by corporate copyrights, so I cannot share the repository. I will keep trying to reproduce the error in a small example, but I wanted to get this question out there in case anyone has any experience with this issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to mock `react-native-reanimated` you don't have to do it manually as they are now providing a mock in the module itself.

Simple add this line to your `jest.setup.js` file :

```js
jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () =>
  require('react-native-reanimated/mock')
);
```

This has been introduced by this PR: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/276/files#diff-1377ba307a14fcbe31e128f4753b73301a43967a417c744f144f9ae5d77f67d5R7

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this as well.

I wound up needing to mock out the whole reanimated module with code like this:

```
jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
  const View = require('react-native').View;

  return {
    Value: jest.fn(),
    event: jest.fn(),
    add: jest.fn(),
    eq: jest.fn(),
    set: jest.fn(),
    cond: jest.fn(),
    interpolate: jest.fn(),
    View: View,
    Extrapolate: { CLAMP: jest.fn() },
    Transition: {
      Together: 'Together',
      Out: 'Out',
      In: 'In',
    },
  };
});
```

I have this in a `/spec_config/jest.js` file, that is loaded (along with a few other global mocks) with the following line in my `jest.config.js` file: `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./spec_config/jest.js'],`

Seems like a hot mess to me, but that's the way it just is in this world, I guess. (h/t this GitHub issue: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/205)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with with react-native-reanimated. Follow the procedure as in
[react-native-reanimated documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/).
It should work fine now. If it doesn't, try fixing react-native-gesture-handler as in
[react-native-gesture-handler documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation).